# How to append query result to a datatable c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I need to append query result to a `datatable` each time the method is called with different parameters. But now each time it overwrite the contents of `datatable` rather than appending.

Is it possible to append? Please help me...

```
Protected void chkrow_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DataTable dtble = new DataTable();
    CheckBox chkrow = (CheckBox)sender;
    gridViewRow gvrow = chkrow.Parent.Parent;   
    GridView gvemp = (GridView) grdemp.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("gvemp");
    string emp = grdemp.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString();
    if(gvemp.Checked == true)
    {
        string sqls = "select * from emptable where empid= ' " + emp.ToString()  + "' " ;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqls, cn) ;
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd) ;
        da.Fill(dtble);
        //here I need to append result to dtble rather than overwriting when each checkbox is checked
    } 

}
```

Comment: Post your  necessary code

Comment: Are you using a temp table?

Comment: Yes. Im using a temporary datatable.

Comment: Not good but you need to define datatable globally, and then append the rows each time check box is checked.

Comment: I tried that. But still overwriting the contents

Comment: Actually my requirement is to get the contents of all the checked rows in a gridview and store that information in a datatable. Is there any alternative way to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable dtble outside your function to make it accessible globally, Populate it on page load, load your grid view and Then -

```
Protected void chkrow_CheckedChanged(object sender,      EventArgs e) 
{
DataTable dtble_inner=new DataTable() ;
CheckBox chkrow=(CheckBox)sender;
gridViewRow gvrow=chkrow.Parent.Parent; 
GridView gvemp=(GridView) grdemp.                   Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("gvemp");
string emp=grdemp. DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString();
if(gvemp.Checked==true)
{
    string sqls="select * from emptable where empid= ' " + emp. ToString()  +"' " ;
    OracleCommand cmd=new OracleCommand(sqls, cn) ;
    OracleDataAdapter da=new OracleDataAdapter(cmd) ;
    da. Fill(dtble_inner);
    if(dtble_inner.tables.count > 0 && dtble_inner.tables.rows.count >0)
     { 
         //something like below
         dtble.rows.add(dtble_inner.tables.rows(0));

     }
     // rebind your gridview here with dtble

}
```

}

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll  try this